# Does the word "hope" require the use of the subjunctive mood?

Tags: subjunctive-mood

e.g. - I hope you be/are fine during your travel

```
 - I hope you be/are fine living in your new apartment
```

Answer (score 0):

Not really, no.

> I hope you *will* be fine during your travels (or you'll is more natural)

is okay.

> *"Notice that the subjunctive is not generally used after verbs such as hope and expect, or after verbs that use a different syntax, such as want"*
>   -- [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_subjunctive#Use_of_the_present_subjunctive) and [Kudos @Edwin](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/193820/does-the-word-hope-require-the-use-of-the-subjunctive-mood/193821#comment405954_193821)

And

> *"In some examples, preserved in set expressions and well-known phrases, inversion may take place with non-auxiliary verbs: come what may; come Monday (etc.). "*
>   -- [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_subjunctive#Use_of_the_present_subjunctive)

Comment: In fact, '... the subjunctive is not generally used after verbs such as hope and expect....' ([Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_subjunctive))

Comment: How can you tell whether it's subjunctive or not? I would think that the _come_ in _I certainly hope you come_ is subjunctive, if anything is.

Comment: *"In some examples, preserved in set expressions and well-known phrases, inversion may take place with non-auxiliary verbs: come what may; come Monday (etc.)."* does that answer it?

Comment: @John Why do you think that? Why would it be subjunctive in the second person, but not in the third? Would that not entail that mood be (!) a characteristic licensed by the subject in the subordinate clause, rather than by the verb in superordinate one.

Comment: But the verb _hope_ is an irrealis verb if ever there was one. If there be a subjunctive mood in English, be it anywhere, it's here. If, however, there ben't any such thing as a mood in English, then anything you like can be called "subjunctive" or "conditional". Why not? Could it possibly confuse people?